# LISP function to print out fibonacci sequence up to N amount of numbers

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write code that computes N Fibonacci numbers (where N is the function parameter). I'm new to LISP and am struggling with the syntax. This is what I have so far... I feel like it is close.

```
(defun fib (n)
(if (or (= n 1) (= n 2))
(print 1))
(print (+ (fib (- n 1))(fib (- n 2)))))
;;;;It should output like so:
(fib 0)
()
(fib 2)
( 1 1 )
(fib 6)
( 1 1 2 3 5 8 )
```

Could anyone help me tidy up my function so that it works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One problem: You've misplaced one of the parentheses belonging to your `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it is [tree recursive](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_sec_1.2.2) and its running time will blow up exponentially. The link has efficient alternatives. But, if you want to keep the whole sequence you could do something like,

```
(defun fib (num)
  (let (seq)
    (labels ((helper (n)                                  ; define local helper function
               (when (<= n num)                           ; stop when reached NUM
                 (if (< n 3) (push 1 seq)
                     (push (+ (car seq) (cadr seq)) seq)) ; sum of previous 2
                 (helper (1+ n)))))                       ; recurse
      (helper 1))                                         ; start from first fib number
    (nreverse seq)))                                      ; reverse the result
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `(1 1)` from evaluating `(fib 2)` in the REPL then you are not expecting anything to be printed, just that the list `(1 1)` is to be returned.

```lisp
;; using recursion. 
(defun fib (limit)
  (labels ((helper (n a b)
             (if (> n limit)
                 '()
                 (cons a (helper (1+ n) b (+ a b))))))
    (helper 0 0 1)))

;; using tail recursion. Usually tail call optimized when 
;; compiled, but it's not a requirement in the standard.
(defun fib (limit)
  (labels ((helper (n a b acc)
             (if (> n limit)
                 (nreverse acc)
                 (helper (1+ n) b (+ a b) (cons a acc)))))
    (helper 0 0 1 '())))

;; Using loop. Never blows stack.
(defun fib (limit)
  (loop :for a := 0 :then b
        :and b := 1 :then (+ a b)        
        :repeat limit
        :collect a))
```

I think all these are equally readable so there is no reason not to go for the `loop` version that is the safest in any implementation.

Note that the first [fibonacci](https://oeis.org/A000045) number is 0 and that my code reflects that.

Comment: In that `loop`, you do not need `tmpa` if you do parallel stepping using `:and`.  `:For n :upto limit` can also be clearer as `:repeat limit`.

Comment: @Svante I knew `:repeat` but `:and` I've never used before and thus learned something new. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can use an auxiliary procedure with a continuation to solve the problem.

This procedure is tail recursive yet does *not* require reversing the accumulated list of fibonacci numbers.

```
(define (fib n)
  (define (aux n a b k)
    (if (zero? n)
        (k (list a))
        (aux (sub1 n)
             b
             (+ a b)
             (lambda (rest) (k (cons a rest))))))
  (aux n 0 1 identity))

(fib 0)  ;; => '(0)
(fib 1)  ;; => '(0 1)
(fib 2)  ;; => '(0 1 1)
(fib 10) ;; => '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```

The code here is racket, but you could translate it to Lisp with relative ease.